# Plot must contain exactly one panel; marginal box plot on faceted scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I am very new to programming, but I managed to get around making faceted  scatterplots and marginal box plots for scatter plots using advice in the link below: http://www.lreding.com/nonstandard_deviations/2017/08/19/cowmarg/

My question is how can I make marginal boxplots on my faceted scatterplot?

My code is:

```
CN<-read.csv("LfFlw.csv")
library(ggplot2)
```

Simple scatter plot:

```
ggplot(data=CN, aes(x=PlantOrder, y=CN, colour=Tissue))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~Population, scales="free_x", nc=2)
```

Scatterplot black and white:

```
sc<-ggplot(data=CN, aes(x=PlantOrder, y=CN, shape=Tissue))+geom_point()+facet_wrap(~Population, scales="free_x", nc=2)
sc
```

Scatter plot with labelled axes:

```
sc_lab<-sc+labs(x="Individual plants (ordered)", y="Cyanide (ug g^-1 dw)")
sc_lab
```

Scatter plot with labelled axes and classic theme:

```
sc_lab_th<-sc_lab+theme_classic()
sc_lab_th
```

Scatter plot with labelled axes and classic theme with changed shapes:

```
s<-sc_lab_th+scale_shape_manual(values=c(8,2))
s
```

Boxplot with facet and white/grey:

```
y_box <- axis_canvas(s, axis = "y") + geom_boxplot(data = CN, outlier.shape = 1, aes(x = 0, y = CN, fill=Tissue)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Population, scales="free_x", nc=2)+scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "grey"))
y_box

library(cowplot)

ggdraw(insert_yaxis_grob(s, y_box, position = "left"))
```

And here I end up with an error:

> Error in get_panel(grob) : Plot must contain exactly one panel

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, by either making your dataset available, providing it via the output of `dput()`, or (preferred) making up a simplified dataset that has the same key features as your real one. See also [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You can't. (At least not via the `axis_canvas()` / `insert_yaxis_grob()` route. The error message tells you exactly what's going on: The function `insert_yaxis_grob()` can only insert plots that consist of a single panel. You've made a faceted plot, which contains multiple panels.